# Probability of a 9 shrews to have a total mass of 100g. Please help!

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The mass of a species of shrew is approximately normally distributed with a **mean of 10** grams and **STD of 5 grams**, then:

A. What is the probability that a random sample of **9 shrews** had a **total mass of more than 100 grams?**

B. What is the probability that a **sample of 10 shrews had a mean greater than 12 grams**?

I have no idea how to do part A of the problem...? How should I set the problem when I'm looking for a ***total mass*** of more than 100? Please help.

I'm pretty sure my part B of the problem is correct. Does it look right?

Thank you so much.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let random variables $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_9$ be the individual masses. Let $Y=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_9$ be the sum of the masses.

If we assume that the $X_i$ are independent, then $Y$ has (approximately) normal distribution, mean $90$, standard deviation $\sqrt{9}\cdot 5$.

We want the probability that a normally distributed random variable with mean $90$ and standard deviation $15$ is $\gt 100$. You probably know how to handle this.

The procedure used for b) is correct. If you *interpolate* in the standard normal table, the $0.8962$ is not quite right, the truth is closer to $0.8971$. However, the "normal" model is only approximate, so we cannot reasonably expect $3$ decimal place accuracy.

Comment: So, it will be just --> (100-90)/15 = .6667 --> .7486 (z table) and then 1-.7486 = .2514 ??

Comment: That's essentially right. Again you did not interpolate in the normal table, perhaps you are not expected to. The true value for $0.666\dots$ is a bit lower than $0.7486$.